# Nesting foreach loop in php

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Hi can anyone help me through this,. I'm a beginner learning, please help me nest through foreach loop. Here is the code.

```
<?php 
                        $resource_url = "/app/resources/";
                        $names = array('Affiliate program','Careers','Corporate info','Eco Initiative','Government Customers','Social Responsibility');
                    ?>

                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($names as $arr) {
                                $links = array('affiliate_program','careers','corporate_info','eco','government','responsibility');
                                foreach($links as $url){
                                echo "<li><a href=\"";
                                echo $resource_url; 
                                echo $url;
                                echo "\">";
                                echo $arr;
                                echo "</a></li>";
                                }
                            }?>

                        </ul>
```

Comment: What is the problem ? This code doesn't work ? Please explain your problem with relevant details

Comment: Code works fine but values of first array $names are repeating

Comment: Having the loop within a loop will, I think, create a list 36 entries long.

Comment: Thats because your code runs through $links elements for every $names element.  You need to use array_combine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$base_url = "/app/resources/";
$names = array('Affiliate program','Careers','Corporate info','Eco Initiative','Government Customers','Social Responsibility');
$links = array('affiliate_program','careers','corporate_info','eco','government','responsibility');
foreach(array_combine($links, $names) as $key => $url){
    echo "<li><a href=\"";
    echo $base_url; 
    echo $key;
    echo "\">";
    echo $url;
    echo "</a></li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've inserted the $links inside the foreach loop. Basically every time you loop one array item, ie. Affiliate Program, you loop the entire array of $links. Put $links outside the foreach loop or better yet.

```
<?php
$resource_url = "/app/resources/";
$names = array(
    'affiliate_program' => 'Affiliate program',
    'careers' => 'Careers',
    'corporate_info' => 'Corporate info',
    'eco' => 'Eco Initiative',
    'government' => 'Government Customers',
    'responsibility' => 'Social Responsibility');
?>

<ul>
    <?php foreach($names as $href => $arr) {

        echo "<li><a href=\"";
        echo $href;
        echo "\">";
        echo $arr;
        echo "</a></li>";
    }?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or - if for some reason - you have to start with the two separate arrays [array_combine](http://docs.php.net/array_combine) or [MultipleIterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way -

```
$resource_url = "/app/resources/";
$names = array('Affiliate program','Careers','Corporate info','Eco Initiative','Government Customers','Social Responsibility');
$links = array('affiliate_program','careers','corporate_info','eco','government','responsibility');
foreach(array_combine($links, $names) as $key => $url){
    echo "<li><a href=\"";
    echo $resource_url; 
    echo $key;
    echo "\">";
    echo $url;
    echo "</a></li>";
}
```

Or generate a single array (key => value) and loop through it.

Comment: Superb. Thank you.. Its Worked.!

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this:

[click me to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TvrH.png)

You can simply:

```
<?php 
$resource_url = "/app/resources/";
$names = array('Affiliate program','Careers','Corporate info','Eco Initiative','Government Customers','Social Responsibility');
$links = array('affiliate_program','careers','corporate_info','eco','government','responsibility');

echo("<ul>");

for($i=0; $i < count($names); $i++){
    echo "<li><a href='";
    echo $resource_url; 
    echo $links[$i];
    echo "'>";
    echo $names[$i];
    echo "</a></li>";
}
echo("</ul>");
?>
```

Comment: @hemanthkumar by the way if one of these answers solved your problem you should mark it as solutions so that everyone knows which one solved the problem :)